# Converting an int to bit array in OCaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml, bit, bitarray

I got an int, lets say 6 and I want to convert it to a bit array.

```
bArr.(0) = 1
bArr.(1) = 1
bArr.(2) = 0
```

Is there any function that does this for me ?

I needed it to be an array so that I can then pass it to other function that receives a boolean array.

Answer (score 4):

The `n`-th bit of an integer `x` can be computed with the following function:

```
  let nth_bit x n = x land (1 lsl n) <> 0
```

An array can be created and initialized with `Array.init` function:

```
  let bitarray length x = Array.init length (nth_bit x)
```

This will create an array of booleans in a LSB (Least Significant Bit) first order. If you need an array of integers, then you can use a function `nth_bit_value` instead of `nth_bit`:

```
  let nth_bit_value x n = if nth_bit x n then 1 else 0
```

I will leave it as an exercise, to get an array in the MSB-order.

Comment: How is that I can call nth_bit with 1 parameter only?

Comment: `nth_bit` is a curried function, so applying it to the first argument (the `x`) returns a function that accepts the remaining arguments (in this case, the `n`).

Comment: It is called a partial application. When you have a function with `n` arguments, you can pass `k` arguments to it, and the result would be a function, that accepts the rest `n-k` arguments. In our case, `(nth_bit x)` is the same as `(fun i -> nth_bit x i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
let int_to_bArr i =
  let rec int_to_bit acc i =
    if i=0 then acc
    else int_to_bit (i land 1::acc) (i lsr 1)
  in
  let l=int_to_bit [] i in
  Array.of_list  l           
;;
```

Test

```
# int_to_bArr 6;;
- : int array = [|1; 1; 0|]
```

Or

```
let int_to_bArr i =
  let rec int_to_bool acc i =
    if i=0 then acc 
    else int_to_bool (((i land 1)=1)::acc) (i lsr 1)
  in
  let l=int_to_bool [] i in
  Array.of_list  l 
;;

# int_to_bArr 6;;
- : bool array = [|true; true; false|]
```